# Retrieving Profile Picture iOS Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm having an issue retrieving the a profile picture from a PFFile column in the Parse User class.  I read in the docs that you need to use the `PFUser` object to query the `User` class.  Right now no image is showing up.  Here is my code:

```
   PFUser *user = [PFQuery getUserObjectWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];

   [user fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
       _profileImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];
   }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The current user's PFUser object is in fact [PFUser currentUser] so all that code in your first line could be replaced with:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
```

(2) Everything else looks OK, but if you're using a PFImageView, your [profileImage loadInBackground]; call should also be within the fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock: async block.

Comment: ... I'm an idiot... totally forgot about the `loadInBackground` method

Comment: But changing that first line is also super important.  I'll make an update to explain.

Comment: Yes, you should really change the first line and others like it. Not only is it redundant, it adds 2 api calls where you only need one.  This is halving your burst limit by doubling the calls.

Comment: @Logan but I think it's an even bigger problem then that because he doesn't actually execute the query and attempts to store a PFQuery as a PFUser...

Comment: I think that's correct.  I didn't recognize it at first either, but it's in the docs.  I think they must have added a convenience method at some point.

Comment: @Logan Yep, you're right. I just checked out the docs too. Never seen in before.